# DotNetZip - How to cancel a "zipping" operation that is in progress?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to cancel a "zipping" operation that is in progress in DotNetZip?

I'm using the following code to zip a folder:

```
using Ionic.Zip; 
...    
using (zip = new ZipFile())
{    
    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\SomeFolder");                                
    zip.Save(@"C:\SomeFolder.zip");
}
```

Now I need to add a "Cancel" button that allows the user to cancel the process, if he wants to.

I think that there's a proper way of doing this, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: There are many different forks of DotNetZip. Which one (and version) are you using?

Comment: I'm using this one: https://s22.postimg.cc/fq5lch1ip/print.jpg

Comment: That's a very old library from 2010 that predates async-IO in .NET. Have you tried using a more modern version?

Comment: No... Do you have any you recommend? I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.0, btw.

Comment: Is there a reason you're targeting .NET 4.0? Only if you need Windows XP support - which I hope you don't - otherwise you should be in the clear to target .NET 4.5.1 as it's the minimum enforced by Windows Update (source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2858725/the-net-framework-4-5-1-and-its-corresponding-language-packs-are-avail ).

Comment: Yes, it's for XP and Vista support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working now:

```
using Ionic.Zip; 


bool wasCanceled = false;
ZipFile zip;

using (zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.SaveProgress += zipProgress;    
    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\SomeFolder");                                
    zip.Save(@"C:\SomeFolder.zip");
}

private void zipProgress(object sender, SaveProgressEventArgs e)
{
    if(wasCanceled) { e.Cancel = true; }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wasCanceled = true;
}
```

Very helpful documentation here: https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/